# Ektron Form including extra fields in Post email (Ektron 9)

Tags: forms, email, post, field, ektron

I'm using an Ektron HTML Form on one of my pages for registration for an event. The Form sends an email to my client with all of the information that the user put in. However, the email includes extra fields with data that the client does not need, and they find it confusing. In addition to all the fields that the user filled out, they're also getting fields such as "cx", "cof", "EktFormId", etc. The client finds this confusing and doesn't want the extra fields, they only want to be sent the info that was filled in (or left blank) by the user.

[image]

This is a screenshot of the email that is being sent upon form submission. We want to prevent everything before "FirstName" from being sent. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The best way will involve a bit more legwork on your part.  If you have the HTML form post to an Action Page, then your Action Page can use Request.Form to pull in the fields you want and then send your own email.

See the [documentation](http://documentation.ektron.com/cms400/v9.10/Reference/Web/EktronReferenceWeb.html#Content/HTML_Forms.htm?Highlight=html%20form) and look for section "Redirecting Form Data to an Action Page"